# Why doesn't the dblclick handler cancel the click handler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**JS**

```
angular.module('my-app', []).controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    var t;

    $scope.click = function () {
        t = $timeout(function () {
            alert('click');
        }, 1000);
    };

    $scope.dblclick = function () {
        $timeout.cancel(t);
        alert('dblclick');
    };

});
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-app='my-app' ng-controller='Ctrl'>
    <button ng-click='click()' ng-dblclick='dblclick()'>push</button>
</div>
```

**JsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6CXW/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting, so when you double click you're calling timeout's cancel only once, but the count em two clicks before that created two timers.  You only cancelled one.

Here's a fixed fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6CXW/1/

And the modified JS:

```
angular.module('my-app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    var t=[];

    $scope.click = function () {
        t.push($timeout(function () {
            alert('click');
        }, 1000));
    };

    $scope.dblclick = function () {
        for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)
        {
            $timeout.cancel(t[i]);
        }
        t=[];
        alert('dblclick');
    };

});
```

Comment: Aha, the second click also fires the click event again. That's some gotcha. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Pickels no problem, yeah I wouldn't have noticed but I did console.log(t); in both functions and then saw something goofy was going on.